# how to type £ symbols beamer Singapore theme

Tags: symbols, typography

does anyone know how to type currency symbols? I am interested in the most used: $, €, £.

Also, how can I change the typography of my write up to looks nicer in Singapore theme?

Comment: You should submit a separate question for the second part as it is completely different to the title of your post and the first part of the question.

Comment: See [write-math.com](http://write-math.com/search/?search=%5Bcurrency%5D) and search for "[currency]".

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question on typing currency symbols, simply use the package eurosym.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\euro
\pounds
\$

\end{document}
```

[image: currency]

Comment: for some reason I got $ when typing \pounds in Singapore theme using Texmaker

Comment: Alberto, please provide a minimum working example.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\pounds89
```